# Adding vegas slider to div background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've got one question with Vegas slider (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/).

I want to add slider as this black background.

HTML code:

```html
<div class="ui inverted vertical masthead center aligned segment" id="slider1">
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui large secondary inverted pointing menu" style="border-style: none;">
      <a class="toc item">
        <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="active item">Home</a>
      <a class="item" href="patron.php">Parton</a>
      <a class="item" href="insygnia.php">Insygnia</a>
      <a class="item" href="historia.php">Historia  szkoły</a>
      <a class="item" href="dokumenty.php">Dokumenty</a>
      <a class="item" href="matura.php">Matura</a>
      <a class="item" href="strony.php">Strony  WWW</a>
      <a class="item" href="galeria.php">Galeria</a>
      <a class="item" href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui text container">
    <h1 class="ui inverted header">
      Życie jest długie, jeżeli się umie z niego korzystać.
    </h1>
    <h2>
      Senega
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basic Vegas script to paste:

```javascript
$("#example, body").vegas({
  slides: [
    { src: "/img/slide1.jpg" },
    { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
    { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
    { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
]});
```

May anybody help me in implementing this script to html? I'm not a typical programmer, I don't know the JS language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `#example` to `#slider1` to match the container ID and replace the `src` values to point to images on your site. Here's an example I tested on your site in my browser console:

```
$("#slider1, body").vegas({
  slides: [
    { src: "http://i.imgur.com/Kf2zBCB.jpg" },
    { src: "http://i.imgur.com/OtjnTqO.jpg" },
    { src: "http://i.imgur.com/Sd44gRr.jpgg" },
    { src: "http://i.imgur.com/MXVqtDe.jpg" }
]});
```

Replace these with your own images, of course.